# SSRS ServerReport Parameters lose pre-loaded value after internal postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

In our website, we are using the ReportViewer control to display SSRS reports. When the user clicks the link for a report, the code stuffs some initial variables to present the proper report, i.e.:

```
reportViewerNew.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ReportURL);
reportViewerNew.ServerReport.ReportPath = ReportPath + ReportName;
```

Every Report has been created with at least one Parameter called "userName". On the report this is a hidden Report Parameter, and the value gets passed down into the Stored Procedure that populates the report so we can track who is requesting the information.

So, in the code we have a Switch block to load up an Array (the length depends on which Report is being called upon) that has at the very least this "userName":

```
default:
    RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
    RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("userName", UserID);
    break;
```

With the array established, we then pass the pre-loaded values into the Report Parameters through the SetParameters method:

```
reportViewerNew.ServerReport.SetParameters(ReportParameters());
```

This all works great, and when the report runs I can check our database and see that the "userName" value has been passed down to our tracking.

However... this ***stops working*** if the report requires some interaction by the user to run the report -- for example choosing an option in one dropdown loads up a dependent dropdown, choosing a date that loads a dropdown with related choices, etc. It seems that this "internal postback" of the report is causing the Hidden Report Parameter "userName" to loose its value, and what then gets passed down is the account we use for the database connection.

I have placed a break-point in the code on the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` line to catch the Report's "postback" but this is not being triggered... it seems to be internal to the ReportViewer control. I have tried looking up some kind of EventHandler for this postback in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.reporting.webforms) but not seeing it.

Does anyone know why the Report Parameter would be losing its value, how to prevent it, or if I need to be handling this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

We are doing the exact same thing but using an Mvc.ViewUserControl wrapper to use the control in an MVC Project. Adding to the MVC project requires us to turn off Async rendering, but these steps may still work in your case, if not with a little tweaking.

We still set the parameters in the Page_Load method, so that the intial report call has the "userName" parameter set,  but we also inject the parameter on every postback call like this:

1. Create a delegate method for the "SubmittingParameterValues" Report Viewer event:

```
private void ReportViewerNew_SubmittingParameterValues(object sender, ReportParametersEventArgs e)
{
    ReportParameter userNameParam = e.Parameters.Where(rp => rp.Name.ToLower().Equals("username")).FirstOrDefault();
    if (userNameParam != null)
    {
        userNameParam.Values.Clear();
        userNameParam.Values.Add(UserID); // Assign your value here
    }
}
```

2. Assign the delegate function to the report viewer in the Page_Init function. This will intercept the parameters every time before the report is sent to the server:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reportViewerNew.SubmittingParameterValues += ReportViewerNew_SubmittingParameterValues;
}
```

That's it!